# Rollup: completely ignore modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, browser, rollupjs

I'm trying to build a lib that works on both the browser & Node.js, with some slight differences. For instance, request should be done using the built-in browser's `XMLHttpRequest`, & `request-promise` on Node. Thus, I'd want rollup to **completely ignore** all import statements for `request-promise`, because checks are done in my lib depending on the environment (browser or node) to switch from one behavior to another.

I've tried many ways:

```
module.exports = {
    external: ['request-promise'],
}

// OR
const ignore = require( 'rollup-plugin-ignore' ); 
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        ignore('request-promise'),
    ],
}

// OR
const hypothetical = require( 'rollup-plugin-hypothetical' ); 
module.exports = {
    hypothetical({ 
        files: { 
          './node_modules/request-promise/lib/rp.js': `export default null;` 
        }, 
        allowFallthrough: true, 
    }),
}
```

Nothing works... I always end up with a require statement, or a direct inclusion of the module in my output.

So, yeah, I'm struggling with it, and I'm praying for some help. I'm not really comfortable with module systems, or rollup itself, so do anybody knows how to just replace the `request-promise` module with anything, even `null`?

Cheers!

Comment: Would you like to ship 2 versions of the same library targeting respectively browsers and Node? Or an unique isomorphic library?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like a different version for each environment: my lib is pretty big and I'd like to avoid to bundle content that is not usable in the browser. For the Node build, I don't use rollup at all, just the Typescript compiler

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out @AlexandreGermain?